# What technologies should i learn in order to be hired as a web developer?

Tags: freelance-websites, web-development, programmer

i passed the last few months on learning web development. so far i have learned a lot in both front end and back end development like

-html
-css
-java script
-php
-mysql(pdo)

my next step is learning object oriented php and ajax and that makes me wonder
what other technologies i need to learn?
do i need to learn how to configure a server and how servers works and networks and all that complicated stuff like nginx,apache,linux....?
in which level i will know that i'm ready for a job?
how to get your first job if the client asks for experience?

Comment: Every client will have different needs. No one can tell you, in general terms, what may or may not be needed. Learn what you want to learn... then *find clients that need those skills*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isnt about freelancing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s about career advice, not freelancing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you say it sounds like you're already qualified to work on projects that use the LAMP stack - (linux, apache, MySL, php) on distributed infrastructure, so custom hosted WordPress sites etc.

There's plenty it wouldn't hurt to learn, bash/linux is really handy. But 9 times out of ten people (especially the kind of clients you'll get starting out with) will be using cloud servers so you needn't worry about the engineering too much.

As Scott says, this is too large a question to answer definitively and you will get hired, there's a shortage of technologists in the market so in my experience people aren't that picky - i put myself through uni with nothing but fairly rudimentary python. Then once you're working you can work out what your favourite things are on paid time.

If you feel like you need experience, try doing some pro-bono work, build a charity website or something. This also gives you the chance to make mistakes with someone who isn't going to be too mad about it.

Hope that helps, obviously there's a lot of scope for differing opinions here so disagreement welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Alec's answer is correct, I just wanted provide a more succinct answer. In today's market, it will help you be successful if you pick either the LAMP stack (which you appear to have made some progress in already, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) or the MEAN stack: http://mean.io/#!/

The LAMP stack is the backbone of most web applications today. The MEAN stack is up and coming, especially for applications utilizing web sockets/"realtime" communication between clients through a server.

If you have a good grasp on relational databases, css, JS, and html, Ruby on Rails is also an in-demand skill. RoR is easy to get started with but notoriously difficult to master, since mastering RoR is essentially mastering the full stack.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, after picking up some basic html, css, and JavaScript you're ready to start working on some small projects. When I first started freelancing I knew very little, but I had the capacity to learn what I needed to learn on the job. I see so many developers bragging about the laundry list of technologies they know when what I would rather see is a few projects that demonstrate **they can actually build something**.

So, instead of focusing on which technologies you should learn, **work on an actual project**. As you build it, you will organically learn what you need to know to bring the project to fruition. Obviously, there are some fundamental skills that every web developer needs to know (HTML, JS, CSS, at least one backend language, some DB knowledge), but it sounds like you have many of the fundamentals down. Your next step should be putting those skills to the test on an actual project.

Answer (score 0):

While the obvious languages are useful, I would say there are other skills that are also required. I fell for the same thing, as a typical developer you want all teh programming skill possible, but fail to realise there is so much more you need.
For developing, you also want to be able to do responsive web design, understanding servers/hosts/ how would you transfer files over to clients server once complete(fileZilla maybe), and sometimes photoshop (because the client doesn't realise they're different skills),

But the other skills I was talking about include things like time management, bookkeeping (if you are declaring your earnings), understanding and communicating with clients (harder than you think), stress management, overall being professional. In addition I would say you need your own website that includes your portfolio. That will help with getting hired.